# Is there anything wrong with inviting friends to a bris?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, brit-milah, parties-celebrations

I have a friend - let's call him 'A' - who's married; His wife gave birth to a boy. I asked another friend of mine, if 'A' invited him to the *bris*. He told me that one is not supposed to invite friends to their child's *bris*.

Does anyone know if there is source for this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Perhaps they are referring to the idea mentioned [here](http://www.dinonline.org/2012/02/28/inviting-to-a-bris/).

That is one shouldn't invite *anyone* to a bris as declining such an invitation would be bad (Rema [Yoreh Deah 265:12](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6752)). But if you don't receive an invitation at all, one can choose not to show up.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. I hope you continue to participate. Please look around as you will find many interesting questions and answers.

Comment: I'd like to second Gershon's welcome. This is really a great answer, +1

Comment: My son's bris was at my parents house and we had a minyan that morning too so we needed at least 10 men. We announced it. Quite a few relatives obviously helped make up the numbers, and some friends.

Comment: @CashCow I don't have a source for this beyond "what people say," but my understanding is that an announcement is different from an invitation -- an announcement lets people know that the event is happening, whereas an invitation is a request for that person to show up.

Comment: @Shokhet See the *Pischei Teshuvah* linked in my answer below. It seems that he's talking about an announcement.

Answer (score 1):

*Pischei Teshuvah* ([YD 265:18](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6752)) quotes *Teshuvos Makom Shmuel* ([responsa #80](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1044&st=&pgnum=180)), who in turn quotes the [*Sharvit Hazahav*](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8960&st=&pgnum=48), that people should not be invited to a *bris*, because if they don't show up in the end (for whatever reason) they would be held in excommunication by heaven.