# PTIJ: Inviting Moshiach to your son's Bris

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Based on the reasons behind not inviting people to a Bris ([Why do we avoid inviting people to a b'rit milah specifically, and not other celebrations too?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59256/why-do-we-avoid-inviting-people-to-a-brit-milah-specifically-and-not-other-cel)) why don't we just invite Moshiach Ben Dovid to a Bris, thereby forcing him to attend, and then requesting he reveal himself and end Golus already?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Forcing him? Not so easy. He has a history of [accepting invitations but not showing up](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.98a.17?lang=bi)

Comment: I don't see how this is a joke. Or at least, I can imagine a Jew asking this question seriously. (Probably a chabadnik.)

Comment: @DoubleAA This seems like an OK joke. If Purim Torah is often Jewish concept + humorous misunderstanding, then in this case it is the idea that you could actually force G-d or the messiah's hand.

Comment: @Mike for better or worse, there are Jews who don't think that's a joke and actually try to do that

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm joining three extant votes to reopen, as I think the suggestion that this question may be read as serious is speculative and not sufficient grounds for closing it.

Comment: @Isaac see http://mi.yodeya.com/q/18767 it's not a joke even if more of us think it should be. The onus is on the purim torah poster to prove his post is not making fun of anyone real. The standards are higher for remaining open. We don't *need* more purim torah posts that we should bend over backwards to allow them. I maintain this should be closed.

Comment: @doubleaa what does chabad have to do with this

Comment: @bluejayke They're the only Jews I know of who've ever tried to implement something like this, as I linked above "the Lubavitcher Rebbe often asked Rabbonim to issue a Psak Din that Moshiach must come now."

Comment: @DoubleAA what is "something like this", asking Hashem to send moshiach? The rambam says that in the end of the exile, the people of Yisroyayl will all do teshuva, and immedietely they will be redeemed (meaning moshiach wil come), does that mean we shouldn't do teshuva, so as not to force moshiach to come?

Comment: @bluejayke Are you saying you don't find the proposed mechanism of bringing mashiach in this question to be a joke as the OP did? I suspect you don't find it funny at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA it could very well be a legitamate way, **if** there's a rule that anyone who's invited to a bris mila has to attend, I assumed that that was not the case and that's where I found the humor, but the concept of doing anything we can to get moshiach to come is one of the foundations of the Toyruh, also the point of bringing moshiach in general is through teshuva, so if the inviting is through teshuva, it very well could be, like the rambam said that every person has to look at the world on a scale that's equal etc...

Comment: @bluejayke Seemingly the possible existence of such a rule is at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48996/759 and surely mashiach wouldn't want to be excommunicated

Comment: @IsaacMoses Please see above. PTIJ is not here to make anyone feel bad.

Comment: @DoubleAA OK cool so there is a rule, I didn't know about that, I try to learn something new every day, so , again I'm no expert, but its possible this could be a valid way to try to bring moshiach, maybe not though, a rav should be consulted to see if there's any problems with it, but certainly we should try to bring moshiach, especially if inviting moshiach is done through teshuva..

Answer (score 4):

At the beginning of the procedure of Brit Milah, the Mohel invites Eliyahu HaNavi to come and help him.

However, the gemara says that Eliyahu is supposed to come ***before*** Mashiach.

Therefore, Mashiach cannot be invited before the Brit Milah starts, and it would be rude to only invite him in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

It says in [Yoreh Deah 265(12)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.265.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that if there will be people at the seudah who are "אינם מהוגנים" - not so geshmack - one would not go eat at the seudah. Since I would certainly be at my own son's bris and seudah, I don't think it would be right to put Moshiach ben Dovid in that position.

Comment: What geshmack is shown for Moshiach if he learns you wanted to invite him but declined?