# What is Invitation?

Tags: halacha, minhag, social-convention, parties-celebrations

It seems to be a Jewish custom (even great Rabbis do it) to invite people to at least weddings (maybe also bar mitzvah (but maybe not to a [bris](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48996/5120))

What is the idea of this invitation?
Is it a command telling them to come?
Is it a request asking for them to come?
Is it not a request but only informing them that if they want to come they can (and without an invitation you cannot come)?
(The word Hazmana (invitation) is also used when the court askes someone to come to court)

Are here halachik reasons to invite people? (What are they?)
(Is it to help your bride to respect you (so many people come to respect my groom - he is important), as by the mitzvah of hachnosas kalla)

Is it improper not to invite anyone to a wedding (if you will have 10 men there anyway)...? Why?

If someone was invited can he not come?
Is it disrespectful to invite important people (you tell them what to do)?

If the one inviting going a favor (of inviting) to the one being invited or visa versa (of coming), it is important to know so to avoid being an ingrate

### I am interested in "what is invitation?".

The above questions are only to help someone give a more full answer (partial answers still appreciated)

Comment: Invitations to events is a universal social convention, whose utility is evident. Why would you assume there is anything distinctly Jewish about it? Will you similarly ask if there is a Jewish source for the practice of millions of Jews to drive automobiles?

Comment: @mevaqesh it is not evident to me (a klutz) , but what you claim is an answer by itself

Comment: @mevaqesh so I guess I should also ask this (or maybe first ask this by https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com )

Comment: These days, the "invitation" is becoming more like an announcement. More of it is being done online with tools like e-vite. Even if you get a personal email, and even it says, "you're invited", it's, technically an "announcement" (we can debate on semantics.) Point is - if you don't get one of these, how are you supposed to know the event will occur and, more importantly, how would you know if the host cares for your presence (and presents)?

Comment: Are you limiting this Q specifically to a wedding and specifically to a written invitation (either by email, snail-mail, or e-vite, etc.?) Please edit criteria in the question.

Comment: The word *zimun* also implies an "invitation". If 3 people eat bread at the same meal, one person invites the other 2. There are no cards sent. I don't think anyone can refuse this invitation, either.

Comment: @DanF in writing (that is the way Rabbis do it ) or aurally

Comment: You mean "orally" - by speech or using the mouth. "Aurally" means using the ears. Funny thing is that they are pronounced alike and sound alike. Go figure!